# Map object key to value type in class generic

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have the following code:

```js
interface Person {
    name: string;
    age: number;
} 

class Store<T, K extends keyof T> {
    constructor(private obj: T) { }

    get(key: K): T[typeof key] {
        return this.obj[key];
    }
}

const person: Person = {
    name: 'John',
    age: 99
};

const store = new Store(person);
const value = store.get('name');
```

`value` type shows:

```
const value = store.get('name');
   // ^^^^^ value: string | number
```

How to infer the value type of an object given its key as an argument in a class method?

I want `value` to be properly typed as `string` in this case. How to achieve this?

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgArQM4HsTIN4BQyxyIcAthAFzIZhSgDmA3ESXI9aQK7kBG0VgF9kBAggA2cDBmQBlMFigQAPABUANMgDSyCAA9IIACayA1hACeWGMjUA+fG2IIcdKNwSKoACgAODABucJDIWHwAVjRqAJT4yEJiJMicYD4WljTaMdEA2mCWfhA2yBkAuk7Jycpg3FC4YAAWwBgAdOERueWsyYmJ4m5gyEVQ2CA06KM4yAC8lSRklDQA5ABSWI0gyxrOyBxcAJwHBEKsAyB0tN4ocyAQAO7y1-6YODGsrhdDwRLcN1dKCCtVI+ZaLCDLd4EIA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `get` function itself needs to be generic so it can use the type of the argument. This allows it return a specific key from `T` like `T[K]`.

And the `K` generic on the class now no longer makes sense. `keyof T` would be the same thing anywhere in that class, so you can remove it completely.

Put another way `Store` as a class doesn't think any one key is special, so it doesn't need a generic for that. But the `get` method needs to get one specific key, so the type system needs to know which specific key, so you need a generic there.

```
class Store<T> {
    constructor(private obj: T) { }

    get<K extends keyof T>(key: K): T[K] {
        return this.obj[key];
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgArQM4HsTIN4BQyxyIcAthAFzIZhSgDmA3ESXI9aQK7kBG0VgF9kBAggA2cDBmQBlMFigQAPABUAfPjbEEOOlG4JFUABQAHBgDc4kZFj4ArGmoCU+ZELElknMCoBpZAgAD0gQABNZAGsIAE8sGGRNU1i4mgDXFwBtAIBdbR8fZTBuKFwwAAtgDAA6B0dstLzWHy8vcX0wZHNMHBp0KGxcAF5CkjJKGgByACksSpBpgBodZA4uAE5NgiFWTpA6WhMUMZAIAHd5E4s+kFdWPUPumwluU+OlCFq-U2nJiDTB7IAD0IOODBAjAORw2yDGdC+PwgYD+GyBzFB4JAvAEUAIQA)